# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Ca n't create table `auth`.`order_items`

Tags: php, laravel

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Ca n't create table `auth`.`order_items`

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->text('description');           
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
            $table->double('purchase_price', 8, 2);
            $table->double('sale_price', 8, 2);
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->timestamps();
            // $table->userstamps();
            // $table->softUserstamps();

           $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->softDeletes();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
             $table->bigIncrements('id');

            $table->string('order_number');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->enum('status', ['pending','processing','completed','decline'])->default('pending');
            $table->float('grand_total');
            $table->integer('item_count');
            $table->boolean('is_paid')->default(false);
            $table->enum('payment_method', ['cash_on_delivery', 'paypal','stripe','card'])->default('cash_on_delivery');

            $table->string('shipping_fullname');
            $table->string('shipping_address');
            $table->string('shipping_city');
            $table->string('shipping_state');
            $table->string('shipping_zipcode');
            $table->string('shipping_phone');
            $table->string('notes')->nullable();

            $table->string('billing_fullname');
            $table->string('billing_address');
            $table->string('billing_city');
            $table->string('billing_state');
            $table->string('billing_zipcode');
            $table->string('billing_phone');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('orders');
    }
}

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateOrderItemsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('order_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->float('price');
            $table->integer('quantity');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('order_items');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there more to the error message?

Comment: `categories.id` is probably not an unsigned int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating foreign key on `product_id` in your `order_items` table using  `$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')` but  it is definend integer in your products table `$table->increments('id');` that is why you are getting this error.

To create a `foreign key` `child column` data type must be same as of `parent column` datatype

To resolve this error change `unsignedBigInteger` to `unsignedInteger`